# Colored Background for Inserted HTML

Tags: office-js

I'm trying to apply a colored background to text inserted via the Office.js api.

One can do this manually with `Format -> Border and Shading`, selecting Style: 100%, and the desired color.

Shading works on my Desktop edition of Word, but I can't find it in Word Online.

Is some equivalent ability available in Office.js?

Answer (score 0):

You can apply a built-in or custom style to a [Range](https://dev.office.com/reference/add-ins/word/range).

The trick is to have that style defined. This is what the manual Format -> Border and Shading is doing behind the scenes; adding a style and applying it to the current selection. You will need to define the style you want in OOXML and then insert it into the document. For a walk-though on how to do this, see [Create better add-ins for Word with Office Open XML](https://dev.office.com/docs/add-ins/word/create-better-add-ins-for-word-with-office-open-xml).